# How to show next page (Stateless widget) on click only in specific Container in SplitView, not all over the page

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I have TestApp, where I have SplitView with 2 horizontal Containers. By clicking button in the first container on the left(blue) I want to show new page (DetailPage widget) but not all over the page, but only in the first Container. Now it shows on the whole screen. What is a best approach to do it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:split_view/split_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Test',
    home: TestApp(),
  ));
}

class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SplitView(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage()));
                },
                child: const Text('CLICK')),
          ),
          Container(color: Colors.yellow),
        ],
        viewMode: SplitViewMode.Horizontal,
        indicator: SplitIndicator(viewMode: SplitViewMode.Horizontal),
        activeIndicator: SplitIndicator(
          viewMode: SplitViewMode.Horizontal,
          isActive: true,
        ),
        controller: SplitViewController(limits: [null, WeightLimit(max: 1)]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('')), body: Container(color: Colors.red));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When pushing a new page you will be overriding the old one, meaning the new page will not have a `spiltView`, the best way to do this is by changing the widget displayed inside of the `splitView` like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:split_view/split_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Test',
    home: TestApp(),
  ));
}

class TestApp extends StatefulWidget { // I have already changed the widgte to stateful here
  const TestApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestAppState createState() => _TestAppState();
}

class _TestAppState extends State<TestApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool Bool;
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SplitView(
        children: [
          if (Bool == false){
             Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      Bool = !Bool; // this the method for inverting the boolean, it just gives it the opposite value  
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text('CLICK')),
            ),
          }
          else{
            DetailPage()
          },

          Container(color: Colors.yellow),
        ],
        viewMode: SplitViewMode.Horizontal,
        indicator: SplitIndicator(viewMode: SplitViewMode.Horizontal),
        activeIndicator: SplitIndicator(
          viewMode: SplitViewMode.Horizontal,
          isActive: true,
        ),
        controller: SplitViewController(limits: [null, WeightLimit(max: 1)]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('')), body: Container(color: Colors.red));
  }
}
```

Above I defined a `bool` called `Bool`, when rendering the page it checks if `Bool` is false, in that case it returns the blue widget, if it is true then it returns the red one, and when you click on the button it inverts the bool and updates the page.

Please note that for updating the page you have to use `setState` which rebuilds the widget, and to use it you have to use a `stateful` widget since `stateless widget` is static and cannot be changed.

Also I haven't tested the code because I don't have `split_view` package, but you should be able to copy and paste it just fine, if you get any errors please let me know.

Comment: Sorry, but this code doesn't work. I corrected some syntax errors and it's running. It's changing bool value on click. But nothing happened in Container:/

Comment: I moved Bool outside Widget build and now it's works

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Navigator.push` your routing to a new page and creating a new state. I think you should use `showGeneralDialog` instead.

```
showGeneralDialog(
                  context: context,
                  pageBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                      Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> pagebuilder) {
                    return Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Card(
                          child: Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                              color: Colors.amber,
 //show half the screen width
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                              child: IconButton(
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  }))),
                    );
                  });
```

Comment: This is not a great way to do it since you are just mimicking a split view and you will be losing any benefits from using the `split_view` package, for example splitting the view between multiple widgets. @david okoroafor

Answer (score -1):

try to create new Navigator within Container:

```
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navKey = GlobalKey();

      home: SplitView(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Navigator(
        key: _navKey,
        onGenerateRoute: (_) => MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) {
return Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage()));
                },
                child: const Text('CLICK')),
          );
},
        ),
      ),),
```

Comment: I don't know why but works the same as before. Red Container is shown on whole screen, not in blue Container

Comment: how is this different from the original code ? it does the exact same thing @Jim Chiu